# Aiflow doesnt see python libraries

Tags: python, airflow

I am working on a server with shared access rights (each user has his own python interpreter and one interpreter on the server is shared) I have encountered a problem that Airflow, when running a bug script, accesses the "shared" interpreter and does not see the libraries I have installed (ModuleNotFoundError). The `print(sys.path)` command inside the bug script gives the following output

```
['/home/username/.local/bin', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3. 8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/home/username/airflow/dags', '/home/username/airflow/config', '/home/username/airflow/plugins']
```

while the `print(sys.path)` command from the terminal returns the following:

```
['', '/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python310.zip', '/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.10', '/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3. 10/lib-dynload', '/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5_sip-12.11.0-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg']]
```

Can you please tell me how do I change my Airflow settings to fix this error?

Comment: I'm not really sure if it is a good idea to manipulate `sys.path` but it is best to have virtual env. Have you tried looking at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `ExternalPythonOperator`
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).